# AdvancedMarkerView in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

When using Google Maps `AdvancedMarkerView` isn't showing on the map. This problem only occurs when storing `googleMap` in the component. When storing `googleMap` in a const or window object its working fine.

I would like to store it in the component, so I can add or remove markers later. Am I missing something or is this because `AdvancedMarkerView` is beta?

```
mounted() {
    const loader = new Loader({
        apiKey: 'key',
        version: 'beta',
        libraries: ['marker'],
    });

    loader.load().then((google) => {
        this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, this.mapOptions);
        // const googleMap = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, this.mapOptions);
        // window.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, this.mapOptions);

        // Marker works fine
        new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.googleMap,
            position: this.home.position,
        })

        // Works only with window.googleMap or const googleMap
        new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
            map: this.googleMap,
            position: this.home.position,
            content: this.buildContent(this.home),
            title: this.home.title
        });
    });
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vue3 with Advanced Markers works for me, here is my codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-google-map-base-circles-forked-1hbe2p?file=/src/components/GoogleMapLoader.vue

One thing to note is that, in Vue3, it seems using `data()` interferes with `this.map`, after changing `data()` to `setup()`, then it works fine.

Change to your API key and you should be able to see the new markers.

[image]

Comment: Your codesandbox uses vue2, if you switch to vue3 you will see that `AdvancedMarkerView` doesn't work for some reason. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rglufj?file=src/components/Map.vue) for a demonstration. Any ideas why this isn't working in vue3?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I switched to Vue3 and did reproduce the problem, but I played around and found that if I don't define the `map` in the data, then using `this.map` is working for me, see [my code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-google-map-base-circles-forked-1hbe2p?file=/src/components/GoogleMapLoader.vue). I am not sure why `data.map` interferes with `this.map` for AdvancedMarkerView in Vue3.

Comment: One thing to note is that, in Vue3, it seems using `data()` interferes with this.map, after changing `data()` to `setup()`, then it works fine.

Comment: I found out the same thing when defining marker in `data()` it becomes reactive (proxy) and the Google Marker api isn't working.
 
As described in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) "It is possible to add a new property directly to `this` without including it in `data`. However, properties added this way will not be able to trigger reactive updates.".

Comment: Hi @jeantimex and @Thijs this is great thank you. In my implementation using vue3 the map and markers are set using `map.value` which seems to conflict with `AdvancedMarkerVue`. Would you mind taking a peek and any suggestions are welcome, thank you. [CodeSandbox Playground showing Vue3 AdvancedMarkerView Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-googlemap-advancedmarker-d7msy8?file=/components/Map.vue)

Comment: Hi @NickB, the AdvancedMarkerView does not support passing a Proxy to the map property, so a quick fix is to use Vue's toRaw function to extract the actual map value from Proxy, try passing toRaw(map.value) to AdvancedMarkerView's map property, and it should work.